# RewriteCond not matching?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've read several url rewriting posts but nothing that helped me.

Basically on the website we have pages ending with ".html" (`http://www.domain.com/page.html`), and we also keep some other subdomains stuff (`http://www.domain.com/subdomain.com`)

So I'm trying to get this: `http://www.domain.com/subdomain.com`
to be redirect to: `/www/subdomain.com/index.php`

I tried this but there's something wrong with it:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !\.html$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^/.]+)\.([^/.]+)/?$
RewriteRule /www/%1.%2/index.php [L]
```

I think I'm misunderstanding the RewriteCond usage but I can't find out how to do it properly.
What am I missing?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be close to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !\.html$
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.([^/.]+)/(.*) /www/$1.$2/index.php?file=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Note that I've added the last part as a query argument for the `index.php`.

---

Oh by the way:

- Here's the wiki of [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)
- The [howto's htaccess official guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)
- The [official mod_rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

And if that's not enough:

### Two hints:

If you're **not** in a hosted environment (= if it's *your own server* and *you **can** modify the virtual hosts*, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Thanks, it works. Except the second line should be RewriteRule, not Cond.
Cheers,
Rob

Comment: I realized that it works, but this part:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !\.html$

doesn't stop the html pages to enter the RewriteRule

(Not Found

The requested URL /www/page.html/index.php was not found on this server.)

Comment: ok, i finally got it. QUERY_STRING is the list of variables passed after the '?'. So I had to change it to REQUEST_URI, which is actually what i wanted to check

Comment: just stumbled about this while researching some rewrite-stuff of my own: the usual thing to try in `RewriteCond` would be `REQUEST_FILENAME`, `REQUEST_URI` contains, among others, `REQUEST_FILENAME`, but also `QUERY_STRING`, so, depending on what you want to do, `REQUEST_URI` might not be the right param to ask. Imagine the (admittedly very constructed) URL `http://www.domain.com/otherdir?subdomain.com`, which would redirect, although the file requested is not one you want to redirect, it just happens to have the redirect in the `QUERY_STRING`, thus also in `REQUEST_URI`.

Comment: Apache logging for mod_rewrite has changed by version 2.4. Current: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging